# jQuery Multiselect dropdown check all ignores filtered

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery multiselect where I want to use the Filter and the Check All functions. If I have 5k items in the dropdown I want to be able to filter the items and then select all of the filtered items.

Currently when I filter (works perfectly), then Check All, all of the 5k items are selected. I think Check All is ignoring the filtering.

How do I implement this functionality?

I'm using the ehynds jQuery UI Multiselct Widget.
[query-ui-multiselect-widget](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/wiki/Events)

html

```
 @Html.ListBox("ClientSelect", Model.ClientList, new { @class = "clients" })
 @Html.IncludeMultiselect(true)
```

js

```
$(clientsSelector).multiselect(clientSelectOpts).multiselectfilter();

var clientSelectOpts = {
    noneSelectedText: '- Select Client -'
};
```

Comment: Do you mean this tool: http://loudev.com/ ? Need to know more to be able to help.

Comment: Hi, no I'm using the ehynds multiselect widget. I have updated my question to reflect.